# Electromagnet solenoid & DC Power Supply

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Can someone please educate me about solenoids. I did a bit of research into it and I'm not really finding helpful information or I'm just not googling the right keywords, anyway. I'm not sure if solenoids point to the North or the South. Since most online stores title them as "lifting"- I'm using the right hand rule, so I'm guessing it always points North, as a default? Also how do you know which wire on a Electromagnet solenoid is plus and minus? I'm going to use a DC Power Supply and before I do. I don't want to mess anything up, I'm guessing it doesn't have a plus or a minus since it isn't color coded.

I was also wondering if a DC Power Supply could increase the solenoid, to make it even more effective.

Stupid questions, I know. I've been putting together a project for almost 5 years now and a few people told me it won't work, I have a lot of doubt in my mind and pretty much frustrated with this project, just need clarification or someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Solenoids don't necessarily have a dedicated positive and negative supply; reversing the direction of current will just reverse the direction of the field, and therefore reverse the direction of the actuator.

Comment: What about a solenoid data sheet do you not understand? It tells you the force, the travel of the plunger/actuator and the necessary voltage/current. There is not much else to it. Can you increase the force of a solenoid by increasing the voltage? Sure, if you do it for a short period of time, otherwise the thing will burn out.

Answer (score 0):

To fully answer your question you could elaborate more details about your 5 year project. But maybe this will help: The right hand rule will define which end of the solenoid is north if you know the direction of the coil windings. Then the voltage polarity can be determined to predict the north end of the coil. If the coil is enclosed and you can't see the windings, apply a small d.c. voltage and hold a magnetic compass near one end of the solenoid. If the north end of the needle points toward the solenoid then that end of the solenoid is the South pole. (The earth's north geographic pole is a south magnetic pole). The higher the voltage, the stronger will be the magnetic field, but don't overheat the coil. When the coil temperature becomes just uncomfortable to hold the coil temperature is around 60°C. You can safely go to a temperature of about 105°C. If the solenoid has an iron core then it is a lifting solenoid and the coil polarity is not important; it will lift for either polarity unless it has a permanent magnet plunger.